# Find Duplicate character in a String

Tags: java, string, duplicates

I want to return a duplicated char in a string or "-1" if not found.

The problem is my compiler asks me to change the return type to `char` at this line `return str.charAt(i);` but I dont want to use `char` return type, I want to use `String` as return type. Can you help me please?

```
public static String duplicate(String str) {

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            return str.charAt(i);
        }
        map.put(str.charAt(i), i);
    }
    return "-1";
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have a String return type? You are looking for a char, not a String.

Comment: you want to return a single duplicate character or want to return a string which contains all duplicate character?

Comment: Like `return ""+str.charAt(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Character.toString()`

```
public static String duplicate(String str) {

    HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(map.containsKey(str.charAt(i))) {
            return Character.toString(str.charAt(i));
        }
        map.put(str.charAt(i), i);
    }        
    return "-1";
}
```